# remove <p> tags from the_content

Tags: loop, content, the-content, formatting

I've got a post format of Image, and I am running into an issue where the image is being wrapped by a `<p>` tag. I want to get rid of that tag (specifically on the `single.php` version) of those post types.

How can I get inside the formatting in a theme and remove the `<p>` tags, or create any format that I want for the output of this type of post, without affecting posts of a different post format?

Comment: Why does the `<p>` tag matter? My guess is that basic problem is just the styling. In that case, I imagine that a CSS solution is the easiest.

Comment: the <p> is your friend. You should really learn how to use it.

Comment: both of these comments are just bad. html matters for a variety of reasons, but in this case because the user is specifically asking for a solution to not use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, WordPress adds paragraph 



 tags to category descriptions. Stop this by adding the following to your **functions.php** file

```
// Remove p tags from category description
remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');
```

**Simple and easy (codeless).**

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Wordpress automatically ads the `<p>` tags to the content. So it shows up while loading the content. This is with the filter `wpautop`. So we will remove this filter for the `image` post type only. You can manage this by adding the following code in functions.php file.

```
// Add the filter to manage the p tags
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wti_remove_autop_for_image', 0 );

function wti_remove_autop_for_image( $content )
{
     global $post;

     // Check for single page and image post type and remove
     if ( is_single() && $post->post_type == 'image' )
          remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

     return $content;
}
```

`is_single()` checks if a single post is being displayed.

Answer (score 8):

If this post type is called "image", you can create a single template to handle the display of just the image post type.

Just copy your 'single.php' file and rename the copy 'single-image.php'. Now you can control just the image posts. To strip out tags, I like to use the `strip_tags()` function. If you print the content of the post with `the_content()` it already applies the content filter, wrapping lines in `<p>` tags.

Here is an example of how you could get the content of your image without the tags:

```
$imageContent = get_the_content();
$stripped = strip_tags($imageContent, '<br><a>'); //replace <br> and <a> with whatever tags you want to keep after the strip
echo $stripped;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()`.
This may solve your problem and another solution is same as described by @Chittaranjan

Answer (score 2):

Simply add below line of code in your theme's functions.php file

For content :

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

For excerpt

```
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

learn more : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Answer (score 1):

You can use specific post class for the `single-post` or `single-format-standard` and make it hide as you require only in a single page so that it won't be a conflict for other parts of the website.

**Example CSS Code***

```
.single-post .entry-content p:empty { display: none; }
```

**Example CSS Code for specific post format Image**

```
.single-format-image .entry-content p:empty { display: none; }
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I didn't know :empty was a thing!

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to remove the p tag from the content you can use the below code

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to code it based on the solution by @chittaranjan

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_autop_for_image', 0 );

function remove_autop_for_image( $content ) {
     global $post;

     if ( is_singular('image'))
          remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

     return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in "style.css" of "Active child theme"

```
p:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 `p:empty { display: none; }`
@Parthavi-Patel. It's good to make it hide with an empty element is found as removing the native functions is a bad practice though we have an option.

Answer (score 0):

if want to remove from particular page or post you can call this

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

though the query has been answered, I'm posting the below for further reference.

```
remove_filter ('the_exceprt', 'wpautop');

remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');

remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');
```

[Source](https://techwelkin.com/remove-p-tag-from-wordpress-excerpt-content-category-text)

Answer (score -1):

Using `wp_strip_all_tags` you can get rid of all html tags including p, div and etc
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/

`wp_strip_all_tags(category_description());`

Comment: The question is about stopping WordPress generating these tags automatically, not stripping tags from a database string.